# Microsoft Dynamics - Deployment administrator not recognized

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. I have added a user as deployment administrator to one of our servers but when she opens up Deployment Manager she gets the following error

"Only the Deployment Administrators are able to use Deployment Manager. Your are not a Deployment Administrator".

Have checked and she is indeed a deployment manager. When I execute Get-CrmDeploymentAdministrator, her account is present in the list.

Have following are the steps in the blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/10/07/6-steps-to-add-a-deployment-administrator-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx

but the error persists. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by doing the following

1) Removed user from being a deployment administrator by removing it from the Deployment Manager console (Please note that trying to remove the user using PowerShell commandlet Remove-CrmDeploymentManager resulted in the error "System User xxx is not a deployment manager".

2) Removed the user from the table [SystemUser] and [SystemUserAuthentication].

3) Adding the user again as deployment administrator by running the PowerShell commandlet "New -CrmDeploymentAdministrator.

It's a bit strange the Microsoft Dynamics Crm errors when deleting users using powershell and allows it to be deleted from Deployment Manager console.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment administrator that you added should be a CRM user, did you added him as CRM user?

Comment: Yes she is a CRM user as well. As I said when I execute the powershell commandlet Get-CrmDeploymentAdministrator, I can see her in the list.

Comment: did you remove the Deployment manager that have make the CRM installation from Deployment Manager tool?

Comment: No, I didn't remove the original user. This is happening only for a particular account. Other accounts can be added as deployment administrator all right and we don't see any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the steps,  I had a deployment Administrator account deleted(causing a lot of problems).  But maybe some reboots should be expressed. 
**Working with CRM2015**

1) Removed user from being a deployment administrator by removing it from the Deployment Manager console (Please note that trying to remove the user using PowerShell commandlet Remove-CrmDeploymentManager resulted in the error "System User xxx is not a deployment manager".

2) Removed the user from the table [SystemUser] and [SystemUserAuthentication].
**Here I had to remove from [SystemUserRoles] as well.  A Reboot here may have helped with the next steps**

3) Adding the user again as deployment administrator by running the PowerShell commandlet "New -CrmDeploymentAdministrator.
**This gave me an error, conflicting arguments in [SystemUserAuthentication].  But it still added the user to [SystemUser].  Second time around I rebooted at this point.  After reboot User didn't appear in Deployment Manager.  Added the user through Deployment Manager and it worked.  Db Tables look correct.**

At this point, Deployment Manager is working for Added User.  And I am working with CRM2015.  Not 2013.

Comment: It this answer was a question it would be closed as "Off Topic">"a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"